# I'm having RpcTimeoutError commit-configuration

Tags: ansible, juniper

I am using juniper module for Ansible, however I'm having the issue below. Do you have any idea ?

> fatal: [172.31.30.158]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failure checking the configuraton: RpcTimeoutError(host: 172.31.30.158, cmd: commit-configuration, timeout: 10)"}

Playbook:

```yaml
- name: "Configure Device" 
  hosts: junos
  connection: local
  timeout: 50 
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: "Configure op script"
      juniper.device.config:
        config_mode: "private"
        check_commit_wait: 20
        load: "set"
        src: "test.txt" 
      register: response
    - name: "Print the config changes"
      debug:
        var: response
```

Comment: Can you verify, that the service is runnung, accepting connections and your timeout is not to low? The problem is, that Ansible cannot talk to juniper and the community cannot really help here.